# OutOfMemory when loading image from camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-bitmap

I use the following method to get the bitmap from the camera after I took a photo. On my phone it is working properly but I get a lot of users that get an OutOfMemory error here. I included the stacktrace below.

```
public static Bitmap getLastTakenImage(Context context) {
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
    };
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
            .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                    null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
        File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
        if (imageFile.exists() && imageFile.length() > 0) {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
            return bm;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:378)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:417)
    at com.app.SquareCamera.ImageUtility.getLastTakenImage(ImageUtility.java:243)
    at com.app.SquareCamera.CameraFragment.onViewCreated(CameraFragment.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1181)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5293)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is too big to be loaded in memory in its full glory. You need to downscale it:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 2; // Power of 2
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

,I am sorry I can't make a common.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale image so that it takes less storage required to generate Bitmap
Here is community post you can refer:
[Avoid OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890156/how-do-you-pass-an-image-path-between-two-activities-without-getting-outofmemory/31890384#31890384)